# Merge a Hash and an Array in Ruby to form a Hash and add some string to the Array values to be seen in final Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, puppet

Need to form a hash with values supplied from a User as a hash and an array ... The end hash should have the array items as keys and some extra strings added to them to make an acceptable hash that is then merged with the hash supplied initially giving preference to the array items if there happens to be a duplicate key in the hash in that

```
        argument1 = {
             'key1' => 'value1',
             'key2' => 'value2',
             'C'    => 'value3',
        }
        argument2 = ["X","key2","Y"]
```

there is need to add a key and a value string to the array items in that they are as

```
         X => {
             'added_string' => 'added_string2'
         }
```

same for key2 in the array and also Y

the above should be merged with the original argument1 to have the following output

```
       result => {
              'key1' => 'value1',
              'C'    => 'value3',
               'X' => {'added_string' => 'added_string2'},
               'Y' => {'added_string' => 'added_string2'},
               'key2' => {'added_string' => 'added_string2'},
       }
```

key2 field in the argument1 is overwritten since it is a duplicate in the argument2 array and its content set as to that of the other array items in the argument2

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have this argument2.each do |value| result1[value] = Hash.new result1[value]['string '] = 'string2' end ... then i merge it with the argument1 like finalresult = argument1.merge!(result1) ... this however does not create a well formed hash it results to finalresult => {...X => string1string2 ...} instead of {...X => {string1 => string2...}

Comment: Thanks. It's best to edit your question and add what you've tried, rather than add a comment. You can format it better, and it shows you have attempted to solve the problem rather than asking folks to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
argument1 = {
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => 'value2',
  'C'    => 'value3',
}
argument2 = ["X","key2","Y"]

added = { 'added_string' => 'added_string2' }


puts argument1.merge(
  Hash[argument2.zip([added] * argument2.size)]
)

# Hash[:a, :b, :c, :d] => { a: :b, c: :d }
# [:a].zip([:b]) => [[:a, :b]]
# [:a] * 3 => [:a, :a, :a]
```

Comment: Konole getting to test that thanks will be happy to tell you the output

Comment: Have equated the expression to a variable but it results to a string  any way to make sure the end variable is a hash?

Comment: @GideonMaina I don't understand you. Could you explain?

Comment: assigning variable = puts argument1.merge(
  Hash[argument2.zip([added] * argument2.size)]
) ... produces a string varaible not a Hash and since I want to use the hash for puppet I can't any way to make it a HASH? but on the merging it does it perfectly

Comment: puts is a ruby way to print (interpolated) string into the output (mostly stdout). replace `puts` with your assignment and it will work: variable = argument1.merge(Hash[argument2.zip([added] * argument2.size)])

Comment: had tried that without the puts but let me get trying other methods thanks